# Is Oxiclean Free OK to use on a metal brewpot

Tags: cleaning, brewpot, oxiclean

Is it safe to use Oxiclean Free on a metal brew pot? I know that rinsing thoroughly is required after using Oxiclean Free. Is it safe to let the brew pot sit in an Oxiclean Free solution overnight?

Comment: Which metal is the pot made from?

Comment: To expand a bit on the previous comment, if the metal is stainless steel, it's fine.  If it's aluminum, don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using oxiclean for years and it hasn't been a problem. My brew pot is aluminum and I haven't had any adverse affects.